# Virtualenv Python version

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv

I have Python3.5.2 by default on my Ubuntu System. I recently installed Python3.5.4. When I run `python3 --version` it outputs 3.5.2 and when I run `python3.5` it shows 3.5.4.

I want my project to use Python3.5.4 so I created a virtualenv inside my project using `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.5 venv`

What command can I use to verify that my project directory is using Python3.5.4?

Comment: How did you install Python 3.5.4 and where is it installed? Could you edit and add the output of `type -a python3 python3.5`?

Comment: I installed using $wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.4/Python-3.5.4.tar.xz. When I do $which python3.5 it outputs usr/local/bin/python3.5.

When I created the virtualenv the output was 
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in /home/aishwarya/rnn/venv/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /home/aishwarya/rnn/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

Comment: Ah ok, I don't think that's a recommended setup, but I also don't think it will cause any problems. In any case, please [edit] and add the output of `type -a python3 python3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Your virtualenv's `python` binary is symlinked at `venv/bin/python`, so simply run

```
venv/bin/python --version
```

However, if `python3` is 3.5.2, `/usr/bin/python3.5` should be 3.5.2, so I don't think you'll get the result you want (3.5.4). You'll probably need to rebuild the virtualenv with `/usr/local/bin/python3.5` as the interpreter.

Comment: thank you. I did just that. Works fine

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. My Python3.5.4 got installed in usr/local/bin. So I should have created a virtualenv with this path. $virtualenv -p /usr/local/bin/python3.5.

To check what version my project is using I activated venv using $source ven/bin/activate and then typed in $python. It gives the following output. It is using Python3.5.4

Python 3.5.4 (default, Jul 24 2019, 10:56:54) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux